# How to switch between different window.locations depending on answer to window confirm() method

Tags: javascript, settimeout, window.location

I have a page that presents a test, where javascript sets a timeOut to abandon the page if the user waits too much (180") before giving an answer and pressing submit.
It has to be done for various reasons, and I cannot modify the committment.
After 180" on the page, so, currently the code goes back to a beginningpage.php where the user will have to re-enter its unique ID to continue the test.

This is the simple javascript code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href= "beginningpage.php";
}, 180000);
```

Everything runs smooth. Now I need to modify the code to better manage the case. We assume that if the user has gone away, it will not be able to answer to an alert box. So let's say we push a confirm() after those 180".

How to write code so that - when the confirm() windows is displayed - if nobody clicks a confirm button (for let's say 30") the code automatically close the confirm window and leaves the page going back to beginningpage.php?

Otherwise, if the user is still at his desk and is simply wondering about the answer to give, he must be given the possibility to click "ok, I hurry up" to remain on the page for say another 60". That means that after the first displaying of the confirm window, the timeout must be set to a different deadline, not 180000 as before but 60000.

Maybe the idea of using different window.locations.href is not the right one.

How could be the code to accomplish everything I need as above explained?

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use a confirm box... Show a div with two buttons after 180 seconds and then start counting your 30 seconds.

Comment: Something like: document.getElementById('timealert').classList.remove('show') ?

Comment: or a jQuery like: $(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
     (".timealertdiv").show();
   }, 180000);
});

Answer (score 0):

> So let's say we push a confirm() after those 180".
>
> How to write code so that - when the confirm() windows is displayed - if nobody clicks a confirm button (for let's say 30") the code automatically close the confirm window and leaves the page going back to beginningpage.php?

You can't. `confirm`, `alert`, and `promopt` are 1990s holdovers with stop-the-world behavior. (Mostly. Browsers are eroding that slowly over time.) That means none of your JavaScript code can run while the archaic window is showing.

Instead, switch to using modern alerting techniques (showing a "modal" div, etc.) so that your JavaScript code can use `setTimeout` to give up after the relevant amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can never achieve this with `alert` or `confirm` because they block further js execution till the popup is active.
You need a custom modal with html element and a js function 
All you have to do is call `clearTimer` for auto-page reload based on the response from `custom confirm modal`.

```js
var x =  document.getElementById("stopReloadBtn")
var reloadTimer
setTimeout(function() {
  x.style.display = "block"
  reloadTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "beginningpage.php"
  }, 5000)
}, 5000);

function stopReload(){
   clearTimeout(reloadTimer)
   x.style.display = "none"
}
```

```html
<button id="stopReloadBtn" style="display: none" onclick="stopReload()">Still Here?</button>
```

> *I have reduced the timers to 5 sec in this code*. A button will appear after 5 sec. After which you will have 5 sec to click this button else the page will reload.